# Encountering an error importing React on index.html file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

I am currently learning React. I am running into an issue though. Whenever I try to open the index.html that it creates, the JS portion of the file doesn't load. Under console I am receiving an error with the first line:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

The error it produces is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

I am fairly new with React so if there is anymore information needed, please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Try to use `npm start` in your cmd/terminal.

Comment: If you are new to React and JS, I'd recommend you to start with https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

Import syntax isn’t supported. You should be compiling the JSX before referencing it in an HTML file. As a commented suggested, you should start with create-react-app.